# combineLatest is not getting called

Tags: firebase, rxjs, rxjs5, rxjs6, combinelatest

I have the following code

I am new to rjxs programming so wondering what can be the root cause. I am trying to do a certain task and first combine all latest result, then subscribe to assign results.  But combineLatest is not working seems like. What can be the cause ?

```
const downloadUrls$: any = Array.from(event.target.files).map((file: any) => {
  const fileName = ...
  const path = ...
  const fileRef = ....
  const task: any = ...

  return task.snapshotChanges().pipe(
    filter(snap => snap.state === firebase.storage.TaskState.SUCCESS),
    switchMap(() => {
      return fileRef.getDownloadURL().pipe(
        map((url: string) => ({
          name: fileName,
          filepath: url,
          relativePath: path,
        }))
      );
    })
  );
});

combineLatest(...downloadUrls$).subscribe((urls: any) => {
  console.log(hi); // not printing
});
```

Comment: Apologies if it sounds a stupid question: do you `subscribe` to `combineLatest`?

Comment: Are you sure all source Observables `downloadUrls$` emit at least once? Also try passing the array as is `combineLatest(downloadUrls$)` because passing sources as individual parameters is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

The reason behind that combinelatest doesnt fire is te reference of the subject.
You should change to this version. So removing the ... before the downloadUrls$.

```
combineLatest(downloadUrls$).subscribe((urls: any) => {
      console.log(hi); // not printing
    });
```

Combinelatest is for merging two or more observables. Is there any specific reason using combinelatest with one observable? Otherwise you can just change to simpler version like

```
downloadUrls$.subscribe((urls: any) => {
          console.log(hi); // not printing
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

The latest versions of `cobineLateste()` receive an array as a parameter:

```
combineLatest(downloadUrls$).subscribe((urls: any) => {
  console.log(hi); // not printing
});
```